# Why I am getting Negative Decibel (around -70dB) where Normal Speech around 60dB

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, decibel

This is code for **Unity 3D** Game Engine...

I try to monitor sound decibels using this [source scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r1Pv.png) but why i am getting ***Negative Decibel*** ?

In [theory](http://www.noisehelp.com/noise-level-chart.html), sound from Normal Conversation will result **60db** and **even silent room will make 10-20dB**...

any idea ?

Result of Decibel Calculation :

[image]

and below are source code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VR_SoundMonitor : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float DecibleValue;
    public float RmsValue;  
    public float PitchValue; 
    private AudioSource audioSourceObject; 
    private float[] _spectrum;
    private float[] _samples;
    private float _fSample;
    const int QSamples = 1024;
    const float RefValue = 0.1f;
    const float Threshold = 0.02f;

    void Start () 
    {
        audioSourceObject = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        InitVariable ();
        InitMicrophone ();
    }

    //Nyalakan Microphone
    private void InitMicrophone()
    { 
        audioSourceObject.clip = Microphone.Start ("SoundMonitoring", false, 60, 44100);
        while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }     
        audioSourceObject.Play();
    }

    private void InitVariable()
    {
        _samples = new float[QSamples]; //use constanta (3 below)
        _spectrum = new float[QSamples];
        _fSample = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        CalculateAnalyzeSound (audioSourceObject);
        Debug.Log ("Decibels="+DecibleValue+" ## RmsVal="+RmsValue);
    }

    public void CalculateAnalyzeSound(AudioSource audio)
    {
        float _RmsValue;
        float _DbValue;
        float _PitchValue;

        audio.GetOutputData(_samples, 0);
        int i = 0;
        float sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < QSamples; i++)
        {
         sum += _samples[i] * _samples[i]; // sum squared samples
        }

        _RmsValue = Mathf.Sqrt(sum / QSamples); // rms = square root of average
        _DbValue = 20 * Mathf.Log10(_RmsValue / RefValue); // calculate dB
        if (_DbValue < -160) _DbValue = -160; // clamp it to -160dB min

        RmsValue = _RmsValue;
        DecibleValue = _DbValue;
    }
}
```

What's Wrong ? Any idea, please let me know....

Comment: @PeterDuniho so how about frequency (Hertz), will same relative as Decibel ?

Comment: Huh? Hz is a completely different measurement. It has _nothing_ to do with dB. As far as the dB thing goes, see e.g. https://www.bing.com/search?q=why%20%20reporting%20negative%20db%20values%3F

Comment: btw, i have native Macbook Apps that count decibel. its work ( i got 10-30dB)...why unity3D wont ?

Comment: A computer-based dB meter is highly unlikely to provide accurate sound level measurements. There's too much variation in things like physical configuration, mic gain, and audio driver settings for that to be a real value. But yes, some software authors will make an effort to translate the relative dB value to an absolute one. You can do that too, if you really want to. Just be aware that you won't get genuine absolute dB values doing that.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at the code you posted. The information Unity3d gives you is just raw samples. The code you posted averages the squares of the samples, takes the square root of that, then converts to dB, based on the reference value of 0.1. Any RMS value that's less than the reference of 0.1 will result in a negative log value, and you can see in your output how small those RMS values are.